# Running CodePush with Android in React-Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-code-push

After being so close to successfully running React-Native for Android, I ran into the following error.

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/Projects/Wosyl-Delivery-1.0-master/android/app/src/main/java/com/wosyldelivery/MainApplication.java:30: error: no suitable constructor found for CodePush(<null>,<anonymous ReactNativeHost>,boolean)
            new CodePush(null, this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
            ^
    constructor CodePush.CodePush(String,Context,boolean,String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor CodePush.CodePush(String,Context,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ReactNativeHost> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor CodePush.CodePush(String,Context) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I've following the instructions in the repo and not sure why this is occuring even after looking at this https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/790

Here is my MainApplication.java for full context.

```
package com.wosyldelivery;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new CodePush(null, this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }
    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

What is the reason for this error occurring? How can it be resolved?

Comment: try replacing null with some string(ex "")

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Unfortunately same error occurred

Comment: Any other ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Why you are sending `null` to `codePush`?

Answer (score 2):

```
new CodePush("deployment-key", getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```

`deployment-key` is a alpha-numeric string which you will get when you register your code-push account and it can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Change instantiate of the CodePush to this:

```
new CodePush("deployment-key-here", MainApplication.this, BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```